# Java stream groupby and joining at the same time for csv export

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of String:
"blue"
"red"
"blue"
"yellow"

I would like to stream it and get this result:

"blue;2\nred;1\nyellow;1"

so that I get a csv of the colors, with a count of their occurrences.

so far I struggle to get all working, here is what I have:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                List.of("blue", "red", "blue", "yellow")
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        );
// result: {red=1, blue=2, yellow=1}
    }
```

Comment: So sort by value, then frequency? A map is not going to guarantee sorting of keys, unless you use something like a `TreeMap`, that stays balanced the entire time. You can supply your own `Map` implementation.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `TreeMap` won't sort values.

Comment: @shmosel yeah, you're right, it keeps original order... don't know what I was thinking. I meant a `LinkedHashMap`; but the point still stands, you can provide your own map.

Comment: Use a library for exporting as CSV after grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stream over the resulting entries, and concat them as you wish:

```
String output = Stream.of("blue", "red", "blue", "yellow")
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
      //.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed())
        .map(e -> e.getKey() + ";" + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

It's not clear if order is a requirement, but you can uncomment the `sorted` line to get higher counts first.

Note that this doesn't handle quoting, escaping etc. If you need any more sophisticated CSV logic, you'll probably want to use a library.

Comment: Or you can check out Guava's [`MapJoiner`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#withKeyValueSeparator-char-).

Answer (score 0):

A `LinkedHashMap` provider will sort the keys for you.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "blue", "yellow");

        String output = colors.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ";" + entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\\n"));

        System.out.println(output);// blue;2\nred;1\nyellow;1
    }
}
```

Comment: LinkedHashMap does not sort elements by keys, but keeps the input order on iterating.